# Create an executable jar using sinatra, warbler and jruby-openssl

Tags: openssl, sinatra, jruby, war, warbler

I am trying to create a simple executable war file using sinatra and warble. I have a simple lib/app.rb file with:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

class Hiwar < Sinatra::Application 
  get '/' do
    body "Hi!"
  end
end
```

a config.ru file with:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'lib/app'

run Hiwar.new
```

and a config/warble.rb file with:

```
Warbler::Config.new do |config|
  config.dirs = %w(config lib)

  config.gems += ["sinatra","rack","rack-protection","tilt","jruby-openssl"]

end
```

When I execute:

```
$ warble executable war
```

I obtain:

```
warble aborted!
Zip end of central directory signature not found

Tasks: TOP => war:files
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I have seen that if I remove the gem "jruby-openssl" from the list, it does not complain and creates the war file, but when I execute it, it raises a 500 error:

```
undefined method `ssl?' for class `Sinatra::Request'
```

Is there a simpler way to generate an executable jar with sinatra?

Comment: If I execute "rackup -p 4567" it works fine...so my problem is how to develop a war file from sinatra...

Comment: What version of sinatra? I'm getting the same error (obviously from very different code) and I think it may be related to versions.

Comment: Has there been any progress with this question? I'm interested in this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Look at **[Rawr](http://rawr.rubyforge.org/)**, which allows you to use `jruby-complete` to embed the Ruby interpreter within a jar.

I have spent the last 3 days getting a working demo called [FontX](https://github.com/briangonzalez/fontx_server) which converts `.ttf` to various other font formats. Run 'rake rawr:jar' to compile, then `rake start` to view.

**[FontX on Github](https://github.com/briangonzalez/fontx_server)**